# Reading file contents using with statement

Tags: python-2.7, readfile, with-statement

I'm fairly new to Python, so I haven't done much in the way of reading files.

My question is this: if I use

```
with open(sendFile, 'r') as fileContent:
    response = fileContent.read()
```

will the whole file always be read in to `response` at once or is there any chance that I'd have to call `read()` multiple times? Or does `read()` just handle that case for you?

I believe the file will be closed after this call, so I just want to make sure that I'm getting the whole file and not having to go back, open it again, and read more

Comment: Unless an error is raised, the whole file will be read at once. Note that 'r' is redundant.

Comment: BTW, `fileContent` is a misnomer. This is a file handle, and you can simply call it `f`, or `infile`, or something. `fileContent` or better `file_content` should be the name of the variable `response`.

Comment: Ah, good point. Why is 'r' redundant? If that's the case, then does open() just default to read-write if you don't specify?

Comment: 'r' is redundant because it is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you specify a size, the `read` method reads the whole contents of the file.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read :

> If the size argument is negative or omitted, read all data until EOF is reached.